# How to connect to to SAP HANA DB via Jmeter?

Tags: database, jmeter

Can anyone please suggest me how to connect to SAP HANA DB using JMeter.
After connecting how to make any query ?

Thanks in advance..!!

Regards,
Hari

Comment: That works just like with any other JDBC database connection. As it is not HANA specific I remove the tag.

Comment: any reference to try connecting ?

Comment: Searching for "jmeter jdbc" yields https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html as the first result. It's already a step by step tutorial, so nothing that an answer here could make more compact.